# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]

Tags: laravel, smtp

i get error in my laravel website. In my localhost it's run, but in my server it's error
this is my env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This my mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tsl'),
 'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
  'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
   'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
      ],
    ];
```

Yestreday the smtp run but know it's error
I have to follow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366993/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-network-is-unreacha) 
but still error. I have to setting my gmail and change my gmail but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
change MAIL_DRIVER=smtp to MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail in ".env" and 'mail.php' file
```

After that run the bellow code

```
php artisan cache:clear;
php artisan config:cache;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how do i can php artisan cache:clear on server?

Comment: no need on serever,,mark the ans as correct ,if it was helpful to you